# Magento2 Product attribute value change in cart and order page

Tags: magento2, cart, orders, product-attribute

I am working on Magento 2, for some of my client requirement is related to change the selected product attribute values change into the cart and order page.

I got so many links that are related to the custom-options changes but didn't get any useful link that is related to my requirement.

I am trying with the following observer on cart page "checkout_cart_product_add_after".

Kindly share your ideas and thoughts

[image]

Comment: Please provide some use case of changing attribute at the checkout.

Comment: I have created a custom attribute with drop-down values, when I selected from a product page and added to the cart, the selected drop-down attribute values will show on cart and order page, Programmatically I just need to change the label of that of the attribute on cart and order page.
Example Select Sizes: 5x5 to Selected Sizes: 5'mx5'm

Comment: So I believe you just need to change .phtml files that responsible for the view on cart and onepage checkout and minicart as well. For identifying template path you can use path hinting through cli command 'php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable'

Comment: Change in .phmtl file is not a good procedure to change the table, we have to do in so many .phmtl for both the front-end and back-end. do you know any other procedure except the .phmt change